# Enzyme: Value props returns undefined in simulating onChange event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to simulate onChange event with `simulate` function. I also have passed the second argument to mock event onChange as the value is part of the event. But somehow it gives me unexpected result as value that I have passed to the second argument returns `undefined` instead of `new comment`. Any idea of this issue?

*CommentBox.js*

```
import React from 'react';

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    state = {
        comment: ''
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            comment: event.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h4>Add a comment</h4>
                <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.comment} />
                <div>
                    <button>Submit Comment</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentBox;
```

*CommentBox.text.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import CommentBox from 'components/CommentBox';

let wrapped;

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapped = mount(<CommentBox />);
})

afterEach(() => {
    wrapped.unmount();
})

it('has a textarea and a button', () => {
    expect(wrapped.find('textarea').length).toEqual(1);
    expect(wrapped.find('button').length).toEqual(1);
});

it('has a text area that users can type in', () => {
    wrapped.find('textarea').simulate('change', {
        target: {
            value: 'new comment'
        }
    });
    wrapped.update();

    expect(wrapped.find('textarea').prop('value')).toEqual('new comment');
});
```

I expect the output of `new comment`, but the actual is returned `undefined`

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110930/simulate-change-for-textarea-jest-test ? you will have to mock possibley onChange props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
        comment: event.target.value
    })
}
```

first do this changes ,its wrong way to set value in comment variable

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below along-with function implementation as suggested by Kishan Jaiswal:

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      comment: ''
    }
  }
}
```